# multiline string of values to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a string of values from a file

```
my_list = ["col1: va11 \n col2: val2 \n col3:va13" , "col1: k11 \n col2: k12 \n  col3:k13" ]
```

I wanted to convert these strings into a pandas dataFrame.

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | val2 | val3 |
| k11 | k12 | k13 |

my python script works but it is complex with multiple for loop iterations.

I tried with `import csv` and `csv.CSVDictReader()` that did not work for me. I also tried `import io; io.StringIO()`. Even this as well, did not convert to a data frame.

```
my_list = ["col1: va11 \n col2: val2 \n col3:va13" , "col1: k11 \n col2: k12 \n  col3:k13" ]

data = [[j.split(":")[1].strip() for j in my_list[i].split("\n")] for i in range(2)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1','col2','col3']) 

df.head()
```

```
    col1     col2     col3
0   va11    val12     val3
1   k11      k12       k13
```

I am looking for some existing APIs that can reduce the complexity in converting the "col1:val \ncol2:val2" string to data frame table format. for example, CSV to JSON

Comment: Your example and output are not matching and the provided code has many syntax errors, please clarify

Comment: Are the 'col1' labels always single words?

Comment: I have corrected the errors in my question

Comment: @IndPythCoder, post a testable fragment of the file instead of a list

Comment: I had converted the each fragment as one line item of the csv file. I cannot bring the data out. This I have posted the replica of the data.

Comment: @IndPythCoder What exactly do you mean by you "cannot bring the data out"? Is your data file in binary format instead of plain text format?

Comment: @Xukrao Here is an example of CSVLoader . https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/csv. I am extracting and processing the contents from the Document Object iterating the  item.page_conent  into a list.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest see the response above

Comment: @IndPythCoder Ok, so if I understand correctly your list with strings was obtained by reading a CSV file with [`langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader.CSVLoader`](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/document_loaders/langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader.CSVLoader.html)? But if your end goal is to generate a pandas dataframe, why bother with this `CSVLoader` as an intermediate step? Why not simply use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to directly parse the CSV file into a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the keys and values are full words, and using a regex:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(re.findall(r'([^\s,:]+)\s*:\s*([^\s,:]+)', s))
                   for s in my_list])
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0  va11  val2  va13
1   k11   k12   k13
```

Comment: This code works for me. Thanks @mozway, I wrote a similar piece of code converting to a dictionary. I am looking something beyond iterators. There are a over 5 million of such records and the time complexity is huge with iterators..

Comment: If you have a list in the first place you will have to iterate anyway. The DataFrame constructor is also iterating internally. What exactly is the origin of your list of strings?

Comment: For a detailed break-down of the regex pattern, see: https://regex101.com/r/VxTlCn/1

Comment: @mozway csv data is loaded and processed into IDE through CSVLoader. This class is from the Langchain.  "from langchain.data_loaders imort CSVLoader"

Comment: Are the values always in the same order (col1/col2/col3)? In this case you could create an array which should be more efficient and you will pass the column names only once.

Comment: yes. col1, col2, col3 are always picked in an order. hmm.. sure let me try.